# C++ Error variable-size object may not be initialized

Tags: c++

K is a value from argv[], length is computed in main

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
 .
 .
 .

 int k_mer = length - k +1;
 int array_of_kmer[k_mer] = {}; 
 }
```

Comment: C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). If you need a runtime-sized "array" use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 6):

Standard C++ doesn't have variable length arrays. Though some implementation, like [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), might have.

To declare array you need to know number of elements at compile time:

```
const int size = 5;
int arr[size];
```

and even better

```
std::array<int, size> arr;
```

If you need variable length array a good choice for you is `std::vector`.

```
int size = calculate();
std::vector<int> v(size);
```